# i am trying to add a url link to an autocomplete data

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, soundcloud

I am new to coding and struggling with a particular section. would appreciate some help. thanks!

I am trying to add the URL like so:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/349298285&color=%23f26016&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=true"></iframe>
```

to the following section of javascript code.

```
// Auto Complete
const ac = document.querySelector('.autocomplete');
M.Autocomplete.init(ac, {
    data: {
      "Nik:11": null,
      "Tell Me": null, 
      "Hypervent": null,
      "Selfish Heart": null,
      "Dont Make Me wait": null,
      "What You Deserve": null,
      "You Did Something": null,
      "Quench My First": null,
      "Rockstar": null,
      "Dreamer": null,
      "Ultraviolet": null,
      "Win your Love": null,
    }
  });
```

In effect, I want the user to be able to use the auto complete in the search and then when they click on it takes them to sound cloud and play that song.

Does anyone know how I can do this also here is the code for the search bar?

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhYCC.png)

Can you explain how I can link up the search bar to the track and also add the embed player on the website.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a MAP or a function to get the ID of each song on soundcloud.
Then, when initializing the Autocomplete element, you need to pass the *onAutoComplete* function executed when the user selects an option.

I add an example below (the tracks id are random), as you can see the changePlayerSong option set the url with song id selected from the map to the iframe element (in this case I put id="player" to the iframe).

```
// Map of songs that relates the String of the autocomplete with the soundcloud id
const SONG_MAP = {
    "Nik:11": 349298284,
    "Tell Me": 349298283,
    Hypervent: 349298282,
    "Selfish Heart": 349298281,
    "Dont Make Me wait": 349298284,
    "What You Deserve": 349298284,
    "You Did Something": 349298284,
    "Quench My First": 349298284,
    Rockstar: 349298284,
    Dreamer: 349298284,
    Ultraviolet: 349298284,
    "Win your Love": 349298284
};

// Changes the iframe with id="player" url to display the new soundcloud song
function changePlayerSong(songId) {
  return `https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/${songId}&color=%23f26016&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=true`;
};

// Configure the Autocomplete onload
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const ac = document.querySelector(".autocomplete");
  M.Autocomplete.init(ac, {
    data: {
      "Nik:11": null,
      "Tell Me": null,
      Hypervent: null,
      "Selfish Heart": null,
      "Dont Make Me wait": null,
      "What You Deserve": null,
      "You Did Something": null,
      "Quench My First": null,
      Rockstar: null,
      Dreamer: null,
      Ultraviolet: null,
      "Win your Love": null
    },
    // Autocomplete function callback that is triggered when the user selects some value
    onAutocomplete: function(value) {
      document.querySelector("#player").src = changePlayerSong(SONG_MAP[value]);
    }
  });
});
```

Breaking down the functions:

```
onAutocomplete: function(value) {
    document.querySelector("#player").src = changePlayerSong(SONG_MAP[value]);
}
```

This function gets the autocomplete result that the user selects, for example if the user selects the "Selfish Heart" option when typing, value will be "Selfish Heart".
Then doing SONG_MAP[value] will return us the songId declared at the start, for example SONG_MAP["Selfish Heart"] will return 349298281. Here, we already got the songId to pass as parameter to the player. To make that we use the changePlayerSong function.

```
function changePlayerSong(songId) {
  return `https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/${songId}&color=%23f26016&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=true`;
};
```

As you can see, this function receives a parameter called songId that will contain the number of the song that we retrieved before from the map.
This function will return the SoundCloud URL of the song, note that the ${songId} syntax will replace ${songId} with the content of the variable, in this case the number received as parameter.

Again on our onAutoComplete function, we already have the result of the changePlayerSong function with the URL of the player. Now we are replacing the source of the iframe that is displaying the player with the following instruction

```
document.querySelector("#player").src = changePlayerSong(SONG_MAP[value]);
```

This sentence will look for the element that have id="player" in our HTML and will change the src (source) property with the new URL of the selected song

Reach me if you need help or more information!

Comment: i did exactly what you said, it works to some degree, i click on the search bar type the song i want or select from autocomplete and it takes me to the song for example hypervent. but when i want to go to another song it just reloads the same song.

now i copied the process link the id to the map then link the function to the id on autocomplete. can you explain what is going wrong.

Comment: You are explicitly setting one value of the map on the functions instead getting the one provided by the autocomplete.

Comment: i did add my code that i had done, but it looks like the moderators have deleted the edited version of my question.

Comment: Yeah, you tried to edit my message, instead of that you should post a new comment. Anyways, I saw your code

I created a codepen on the following url: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KEggzw

I added more comments to the code, specially in the functions that you had wrong. Basically, you had a static value for the songs, instead of setting them dinamically with the value of the autocomplete. Check it out and tell my any doubt!

Comment: Hi Sergio, thank you for your help so far. i am literally new to coding never built my own site before so you will have to forgive me as i dont understand everything something that when i see the correct solution i will know for future thats hows you do it. however think of it like a baby learning his first words and he just doesnt get it lol please review it still does the same as before.  https://codepen.io/Bjorn_Ironside1986/pen/JzRWpp

Comment: Sure don't worry. The main mistake that you are doing is trying to duplicate the functions when you only need one and the data received as parameter is the dynamic values.
For example, in your code, the function changePlayerSong has 3 returns. That is wrong as a function only can return a value once. So, as you see you have the parameter songId being received by the function. This songId will be the number of the song like 349298285 or 348569831. So you only have to return the url modifying the part of the url with ${songId}, this will make ${songId} to be 349298285 or the parameter received

Comment: The other problem is when defining the onAutoComplete functions, again you have 3 functions when only one can exist. In this case the parameter received will be the text that the user selects in the autocomplete. For example if you type and select "Selfish Heart", the parameter that the function receives will be "Selfish Heart". So doing SONG_MAP["Selfish Heart"] will return you the songId of the map declared at the start, in this example will be 349298281. So you only have to declare a onAutocomplete: function(value) { ... where value will be the text selected by the user

Comment: you my friend are a god i am ever so grateful, thank you for your patience and understanding :D